# Get the VS Code ${workspaceFolder} variable from outside of VS Code?

Tags: node.js, bash, visual-studio-code

I have a bash script that I run in a VS Code integrated terminal. Is there any way for me to programatically get the value of VS Codes `${workspaceFolder}` variable? Is there any way for me to access `${workspaceFolder}` either from `bash` or using a `node.js` script maybe with the VS Code extension API or something like that? Maybe getting VS Code to run a task without using the GUI?

Comment: Why not `$ pwd`?

Comment: @JBallin Because the script may not be run from the project root. So if I invoke `pwd` from `projectroot/foo` then `pwd` does give not the project root.

Comment: why not always run the script in root or use logic to determine the root programmatically (e.g. check for files you expect to exist in root such as package.json, .git, etc)

Comment: This script has alternate functionality based on where is is run from. I do check for files I expect to exist in root to check that however in this case I do need the actual project root path. I have resorted to using an .env file with a hardcoded value in it.

Comment: start the script with a task and give `${workspaceFolder}` as argument, give the script commandline options `-w /home/user/projects/great`